# Real Time Update for stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, live-refresh

Are we getting any soon a real time update for stackoverflow questions(posts)?

Comment: The plethora of RSS feeds aren't good enough for you?

Comment: We already have many real-time update methods.  Please narrow down your question by defining what you consider a real-time update feed.

Comment: We need something more real-time. Something... Something ahead-of-time! That's it!

Comment: I mean somthing here like FriendFeed Real-Time update (facebook real-time update) like seeing the answers and comments immediately  when they posted.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `#sobot` channel on IRC (freenode) that shows new questions as they appear.